# Problem with opening .exe file with wine

Tags: 14.04, wine

I having problems running a .exe file named HorseRacingFantasy3_10.90.8.exe. I [downloaded](http://horseracegame.com/downloads/HorseRacingFantasy3_10.90.8.exe) it from [Horseracegame.com](http://horseracegame.com).

Its a desktop client extension file. After installing the .exe file, I tried to open it with wine. After installing wine on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I tried to open a .exe file through wine windows program downloader. The program downloads but when  click on the wine (version 1.6.2) icon of that program it just keeps processing without opening.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Wine tries to emulate a windows environment. Depending on the exe-file it does this with more or less success. Check https://appdb.winehq.org/ to find out what your chances are.

Comment: ITs a game file ,I am trying to open and generally after we download the program ,fter clicking finish button it has to close and open the program,but the finish still keeps appearing without closing and opening the program automatically.I have registered in appdb.winehq.org,thanks madmike for the link,but i prefer a solution in this forum.

Comment: Hi madmike,i am trying to open a horse racing game file,HorseRacingFantasy3_10.90.8.exe ,after clicking this file a program downloads,then after clicking finish button it doesnot open the actual program,I am using wine 1.6.2.